# Not getting the entire <li> line using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to extract the list items under the class "secondary-nav-main-links" from the https://www.champlain.edu/current-students web page. I thought my working code below would extract the entire "li" line but the last portion, "/li", is placed on its own line. I included screen captures of the current output and the indended output. Any ideas? Thanks!!

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen('https://www.champlain.edu/current-students')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
soup = bs.find(class_='secondary-nav secondary-nav-sm has-callouts')
for div in soup.find_all('li'):
    print(div)
```

Current output:
[capture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxKFi.jpg)

Intended output:
[capture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DSlv.jpg)

Comment: Why does this matter? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Was trying to capture the entire line instead of having it broken up into two lines.

Comment: @zeusbella what difference does it make? is there any particular reason you wanted the newline removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the newline character with `str.replace`
And you can unescape html characters like `&amp;` with `html.unescape`

```py
str(div).replace('\n','')
```

To replace `&amp;` with `&`, add this to the print statement

```py
import html
html.unescape(str(div))
```

So your code becomes

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html

html = urlopen('https://www.champlain.edu/current-students')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
soup = bs.find(class_='secondary-nav secondary-nav-sm has-callouts')
for div in soup.find_all('li'):
    print(html.unescape(str(div).replace('\n','')))
```

Comment: @zeusbella upvote and mark it as answer then. Thanks